# How to repair vinyl wrapped front door frame

Tags: doors, vinyl, front-door

Vinyl wrapped front door frame has bubbling in spots. I’m not sure if it’s caused by water or sun or just age. Home is approximately 25 years old. I can only assume this is the original door too. How would one repair something like this? I almost want to “inject” adhesive of sorts behind the bubble and simply push it back down. I think trying to remove the wrap would make a mess. Not sure what would even be behind it. Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I don't consider that repairable. You'll have a hard time flattening it and keeping it flat.

Have a siding company with a variety of aluminum roll stock colors available come by and brake some caps for those jamb sections. They should be able to get them to fit snug and neatly. A few color-matched trim nails or just some adhesive will hold it in place.

Even though the color may not match perfectly it'll look much better than it does now. There's already variation in the brick, so as long as they wrap both sides and the head it'll be ok.

Comment: Did you notice this is a DIY forum ?

Comment: Did you notice that very few people have personal access to a metal brake? This isn't something that can be easily done DIY.